# Foreignkey in Django. How to properly create models

Tags: python, django, model

I am new to Django and I am trying to create a model for a website I am developing. So far I know how to implement everything I want to, but there is one thing that I cannot properly understand. So my idea is the following, in the models:

A class "Class" that can have as many "Teacher" and "Student" as wanted by the admin. I've been playing for a while with foreign key, but I can only manage to associate one student and teacher to a class, and whenever I want to display the "Class" info there is no Student or Teacher to display.

```
from django.db import models
from datetime import datetime
# Create your models here.

LANGUAGE_CHOICES = (
('english','ENGLISH'),
('spanish', 'SPANISH'),
('german','GERMAN'),
('french','FRENCH'),
('portuguese','PORTUGUESE'),
)

class Clase(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    language = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=LANGUAGE_CHOICES, default='english')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    clase = models.ForeignKey(Clase, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Teacher(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    total_earnings = models.IntegerField()
    month_earnings = models.IntegerField()
    clase = models.ForeignKey(Clase, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since a `Clase` can have 'as many "Teacher" and "Student" as wanted' it may make sense to define the relationships with `ManyToManyFields`. I assume a `Teacher` and a `Student` can have more than 1 `Clase`?

```
class Clase(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    language = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=LANGUAGE_CHOICES, default='english')
    students = models.ManyToManyField(Student)
    teachers = models.ManyToManyField(Teacher)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Then you can remove the foreign keys on the `Student` and `Teacher` models. Now when you edit a `Clase` in the admin you should be able to add as many students and teachers as you want

Comment: One is not supposed to say thanks here, but I cannot avoid it. It worked perfectly, thank you very much !

Comment: My pleasure! :)